# Can't open edit module, get error from JRouter::getInstance('site') in joomla 3.9.x

Tags: joomla-3.x, module, router, joomla-3.9

I have the code: `$uri = JUri::getInstance(); $router = JRouter::getInstance('site'); $vars = $router->parse($uri);` I'm wanting to parse the uri out at the module's backend (Just the module I'm writing myself.). But when I installed the module and clung to the module for editing, it led me to the blank page, and in the address bar I saw a lot of `/index.php/en/index.php/en...` it popped up a lot. That is I test with 3.9.x. With 3.8.x it says "Allow memory .....". 
I'm using php 7.2.12.

Comment: I replaced `$router = JRouter::getInstance('site');` with `$router = JRouter::getInstance('administrator');` and the module is now running normally. Are there two different ways? Thank you

Comment: Yes, `site` and `administrator` are the two halves of the Joomla beast.  `administrator` refers to the "backend".

Comment: If you have resolved your issue, you may post your solution as an answer.  If you still have something that you need support with, please edit your question once again to isolate where you would like help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[SOLVED] change `site` to `administrator`